# How to define CSS rules relative to previously defined values witout re-writing them?

Tags: css

For the goal of browser compatibility I would like to load an additional CSS compatibility file for each browser that needs it, so that my original CSS remains intact. In that compatibility CSS I would like to add/subtract numeric values to/from original CSS rules. For example:

**main.css**

```
padding:10px 20px;
```

**ie.css**

```
padding-bottom:{original 10px} - 2px;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked into using a CSS reset to "normalise" element styles across browsers?

Comment: The only way to do this is to use a preprocessor (look into SASS or LESS - you _will_ love them. Mostly SASS, that is. Because LESS... is just less ;) ). You can't reference other previously declared values in CSS.

Comment: @Shaggy Yes reset.css is alredy implemented but certain things slip through like different vertical text alignment within the height of `line-height` and different implementations of CSS generated graphics like `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use SASS: http://sass-lang.com/guide

In particular, I would look into using  Operators, I think that is exactly what you need....

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery is able to do this too.**

```
.css('padding-bottom', '-=2')
```

From the docs:

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to
>   .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to
>   increment or decrement the current value.

http://api.jquery.com/css/